# jquery mySQL timestamp conversion coding bug

Tags: jquery, mysql, ruby-on-rails, timestamp, countdown

I have an application where I need to convert a mySQL datetime stamp and countdown to the current system time. I'm using the keith wood jquery countdown, which is installed correctly and works... but I can't get the code to convert my timestamp working to save my life.

I found this code snippet somewhere to convert the timestamp but I'm getting an error in my firefox console that reads: timestamp.replace is not a function. I'm not an expert in js coding so I'm sure it's something obvious. Any help that anyone can provide would be much appreciated. This is starting to make me nuts.

This is a rails application.

```
$(document).ready(function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
    //function parses mysql datetime string and returns javascript Date object
    //input has to be in this format: 2007-06-05 15:26:02
    var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
    var parts=timestamp.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');
    return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textLayout').countdown({until: mysqlTimeStampToDate("#work_order_hard_completion_datetime"), layout: '{dn}d {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
$(document).ready(function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
    // ...
});
```

You're tell jQuery to run your `mysqlTimeStampToDate` function when the document is ready, you're not defining a global `mysqlTimeStampToDate` function for later use. Then, when jQuery runs your function, it will be [executed with the jQuery object as its argument](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) so `timestamp` is actually jQuery's `$` when your function is run and there is no `replace` method on `$`.

Run this with your console open and you'll see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eUNS3/

I think you just want to say this:

```
function mysqlTimeStampToDate(timestamp) {
    //function parses mysql datetime string and returns javascript Date object
    //input has to be in this format: 2007-06-05 15:26:02
    var regex=/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/;
    var parts=timestamp.replace(regex,"$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6").split(' ');
    return new Date(parts[0],parts[1]-1,parts[2],parts[3],parts[4],parts[5]);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textLayout').countdown({until: mysqlTimeStampToDate("#work_order_hard_completion_datetime"), layout: '{dn}d {hnn}{sep}{mnn}{sep}{snn}'});
});
```